# How to extract price using javascript from coingecko API in a nested array

Tags: javascript, api

I've had success gathering price from cryptocompare.com as below:

```
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=GRIN&tsyms=USD
```

returns:

```
{“USD”:0.996}
```

Notice how the USD price is not nested.

When trying to use coingecko's API, the price is nested. For example:

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd
```

returns:

```
{"bitcoin":{"usd":7238.46}}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to alter the javascript to locate the price.

The pertinent code is below:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd", function(data){
    $("#BTCPrice").text(data["usd"].toFixed(2));
}).fail(function( dat, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    alert(err);
});
```

This code would work for the non-nested data, but not the nested. I'm sure it's a matter of adding something like

```
$(#BTCPrice").text(data["bitcoin":"usd"].toFixed)2));
```

But I just can't get the syntax right.

Comment: I am not sure where <code></code> come into play. If you were trying to indicated a section of text was code, just use 3 backticks at the start of a line. Complete it with 3 more back ticks. The second example has an object with a key of "bitcoin".. It's data is itself an object with a key of "usd" and value of 7238.46

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to learn how to traverse the JSON data. [Check this out.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

In this case, you should be able to get at that value with something like:

```
data["bitcoin"]["usd"]
```

or

```
data.bitcoin.usd
```

Comment: But would op know currency code always? The way I showed below caters for variances in currency code.

Comment: @JGFMK, That's true. Even though OP's question didn't include anything about unknown object keys, yours is the more robust solution. I upvoted you.

Comment: Thanks thingEvery, I knew it was a simple solution. Any you're right about me needing to learn to traverse the JSON data. There are many things I need to learn. But, thanks again. Problem solved using your first suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help you?

```js
var dataString = "{\"bitcoin\":{\"usd\":7238.46}}";
var dataJSON = JSON.parse(dataString);
var bitcoinObject = dataJSON["bitcoin"];
console.log(bitcoinObject);
var curr = Object.keys(bitcoinObject)[0];
console.log(curr); // usd
console.log(dataJSON["bitcoin"][curr]); // 7238.46
```